# Get the value from other table to insert into table that related?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 table with related each other

```
table1 (for insert)
*******************
id1 |   lable    |     line1

table2
********************
id2 |   id1  |  id3

table3
*******************
id3 | line1
```

How can write in the SQL(MySQL) script instead do php script ?

`INSERT INTO table1 (id1,lable,line1) VALUES ($from_GET, $from_GET,How can I got from table3?);`

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what do you mean.
Do you want to make an [insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) from a select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (id1,lable,line1)
SELECT $from_GET, $from_GET, line1 FROM table3 WHERE id3 = $from_GET;
```

Check the [syntax in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing inserts, then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, label, line1)
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
```

You can also do an update referencing related tables:

```
UPDATE table1
JOIN table2 ON ...
SET table1.field = table2.another_field
```

Note that if you're using $_GET variables, it's EXTREMELY important that you clean that input to prevent sql injection attacks.